# Visual Studio Code integrate with Local TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-code

Is there any extension available to integrate local TFS 2013 to Visual Studio Code? Because I don't want GIT to scattered project repositories.

I found some links but it is online support not local.

[Team Services extension for Visual Studio Code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/07/11/the-team-services-extension-for-visual-studio-code-now-supports-team-foundation-server-2015-update-2-and-later/%22Team%20Services%20extension%20for%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update 11/04/2016***

Below is the response from Visual Studio Code team

> **Git works out of the box and we are working to bring TFVC in a few
>   months.**
>
> *Visual Studio Code  11/02/2016*
>
> *Source Link: [Visual Studio Code's twitter](https://twitter.com/code/status/793880006665437184)*

---

Unfortunately, this is **not support for TFS2013** for now. To use the extension with local TFS you have to update your TFS server to *TFS2015 update2* or above. Otherwise, you may have to use VSTS (TFS online) instead.

> We’re happy to announce that the Visual Studio Team Services extension
>   for Visual Studio Code now **supports Team Foundation Server 2015
>   Update 2 and later!**
>
> Source Link: [The Team Services extension for Visual Studio Code now
>   supports Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 and later](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/07/11/the-team-services-extension-for-visual-studio-code-now-supports-team-foundation-server-2015-update-2-and-later/)

Comment: i found answer from VSC https://twitter.com/code/status/793880006665437184

Comment: Thanks for the sharing.